# MacOS Jenkins Subversion Plugin svn update problem

Tags: jenkins, svn

MacOS Jenkins svn update problem(Subversion Plugin ). When I use Subversion Plugin to trigger svn update on Jenkins. The first time to trigger svn update is working, but second time to trigger svn update causes "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155021: Unsupported working copy format" problem.

Jenkins Subversion Plugins version is 2.5.4. Check-out Strategy(Use 'svn update' as much as possible). I have two branches on Jenkins(different svn repository), one is working perfectly, the other one(created on Jenkins recently) only works at first time to trigger svn update, the second time to trigger svn update, I got the error "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155021: Unsupported working copy format". I have tried copy comfiguration from first brach(but only changed svn repository), it did not work. I have no idea why this error only show on new brach. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `svn: E155021: Unsupported working copy format` and it means that the working copy was checked out with a newer Subversion client than the one that produces the error. You have a mixture of Subversion client versions - one appears to be very old, the other one is newer. Make sure that your clients are at the same version such as e.g. Subversion 1.10.x.